# DSL in Javascript or Clojure, given specific constraints

Tags: javascript, clojure, dsl

Domain Specific Language in Clojure or Javascript

I'm considering writing a domain specific lanaguage for transforming and mapping CSV fields.

So for each line of the CSV file, the DSL would execute a set of rules, which would transform and map elements on that line to database values.

An example of what this language might look like / do:

```
# comment

Customer "abccorp"
  Field "email"  # name of field
    Rule "emails must be lower case with no white space" # rule rationale
      Lowercase the value # operation to execute on field
      Strip whitespace
      Assign to "email_address"  # field to map to

  Field "last_name"
    Rule "drop rows with no last name"
      If we do not receive field
      Drop this row

    Rule "must upper case the first character of last name"
      Uppercase the value
      Assign to "lastname"
```

I have the choice of creating this DSL in Javascript or Clojure.  While I recognize either could do the task, I'm interested in the best option given the following:

- ability to create a DSL that is maximally human readable (no parens, no function())
- ease of defining and extending language primatives
- availability of libraries to assist, language constructs to assist
- ability to execute arbitrary language inline (since defining every possible rule is unlikely)

I am barely interested in performance.  If it processes one CSV line a second thats ok, developer time is paramount.

Comment: So you want something like [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) for JS or [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) for Clojure? The language you choose is subjective.

Comment: I struggled with whether to post this questions since SO isn't a recommendation service.  But to me this question is like asking if I should use algebra or calculus to solve a problem given certain constraints, one is more appropriate than another.  Thanks for mentioning PEG.js and Instaparse those are good to know about.

Comment: Looks like you want to validate some online user-input. Note that *just* a user-side validation leaks security issues - but I'm sure you know that.

For DSL in JavaScript see: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/dsls-in-javascript and maybe look at http://xregexp.com/api/ and http://alexyoung.org/2009/10/22/javascript-dsl/

Comment: I'm really looking for something like the Cucumber DSL, without relying on regexs.  Somewhat non-tech readable description of how the data will be processed